# How to handle only one instance of Activity launched from URL

Tags: android, xamarin.android, deep-linking

My app started from customized url schema, built in intent filter as documentation
DataScheme = "mobilepos",
DataHost = "payment".

App starts correctly and receives data from url, but in some cases (example if i press back button) when i go back to url, android creates a new instance of activity.

Which is the best way to use Launch Mode (standard/singleTop/singleTask/singleTask) to have every time an only one instance of my activity?

**UPDATE**
As workaround i set LaunchMode = SingleTask and overriding OnBackPressed i call MoveTaskToBack(true).
This way back/home button pressed always sets app in background and OnCreate is never called when app is relaunched.